# apt-get cannot find package when run through python script

Tags: python, bash, virtualbox, apt-get

This is bizarre. I don't even know where to look for a solution.

I have a python script that automates a ton of installations and options for a system configuration. Part of that is installing virtualbox

```
call("sudo apt-get install -y virtualbox --force-yes", shell=True)
```

so this is it. I run it through python, it returns "package not found" from apt-get. A very typical error that you'd get perhaps with something misspelled, but of course we see here nothing is.

I went ahead and tried the command in a bash term outside of the python wrap and it works every time.

What in the world am I doing wrong? The parent python script is run with 'sudo', not sure if that's meaningful.

Also maybe worth noting this was working yesterday... I'm running it all on Ubuntu 14.04. There are a ton of other packages in the script that get installed the exact same way. It's just this one line that seems to cause a problem in package candidacy.

Comment: Why not just use the [Python Apt Library](https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/index.html)?

Comment: @PaulRooney on a whim I tried apt-get update && upgrade and it works now through the python wrapper. This is weird to me. I'd be interested in why this fixed it if anyone has insight and I'll mark it answered.

Comment: @DylanMoore it looks like you are installing the package inside of fresh docker container. If so, containers' maintainers usually delete the apt package list information to reduce container's image size. So to install a new package you should retrieve package list first from repository by executing `apt-get update` command. Otherwise apt sees the empty package list.